# How to replace lines from a text file and re-write the file with those lines in tab delimited format in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x

In a txt file, there are some items like

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to read and write the file in a tab delimited manner

```
1    2    3    4
```

I have tried the following code

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.replace("\n", "\t")
```

I am getting a blank file. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

when the if statement is true the output is a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    with open("sample_tabs.txt", "w") as output:
        output.write(''.join(l.replace("\n", "\t") for l in f.readlines()))
```

Where `sample.txt` has this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The code outputs a file `sample_tabs.txt` with
`1    2     3     4`

If, however, you want to overwrite the source file `sample.txt` here's how to do it:

```
with open("sample.txt", 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    text = ''.join(l.replace("\n", "\t") for l in text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    f.truncate()
```